# How to access array items in VBscript dictionary

Tags: dictionary, vbscript, uft14

I have a dictionary object in UFT (VBScript) where it contains items that is array. I want to know how to iterate thru every element in that array item that is refered by key.
Below is the example of my dictionary having items that is array

```
Set NodeValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
NodeValues.Add "Nodename", Array("EMS", "ACM") 
NodeValues.Add "MSW", Array("0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34" , "0x25,0x25,0x12,0x12")
NodeValues.Add "SBL", Array("0x35,0x32,0x30,0x31" , "0x45,0x55,0x22,0x92")
NodeValues.Add "Data", Array(array("0x21,0x21,0x21", "0x11,0x11,0x22") , array("0x45,0x55,0x22,0x92","0x25,0x65,0x25"))
```

Since this dictionary is generated dynamically am not sure how many elements it will have in array. Now i need to loop thru all the elements in array to find my required elements
For example. How do I iterate thru all the elements in Array of Nodename ( key) untill i find EMS. I tried different ways to access but no success.

Please help me with solution.

Answer (score 1):

To check if "EMS" is found in the array stored for the key `Nodename`, you can check the following code:

```
For Each element In NodeValues.Item("Nodename")
    If StrComp(element, "EMS", 1) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "found"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

To get the Index:

```
arrTemp = NodeValues.Item("Nodename")
blnFound = False
For i = 0 To UBound(arrTemp)
    If StrComp(arrTemp(i), "EMS", 1) = 0 Then
        blnFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If blnFound Then
    MsgBox "Index: " & i
Else
    MsgBox "Not found"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. How do I know the index position of EMS in the array. So that i need to use that index to find the MSW or Data items in the corresponding array. For example if EMS is stored at index 0, then MSW value will also be stored at index 0 and same applies for others.

Comment: Also I need to read the corresponding values in MSW and Data for EMS and use those values in some other function.

Comment: @SrinivasVenkataram I have updated the answer